# primefaces cropping not word on payara (inside jelastic cloud)

Tags: primefaces, payara, jelastic

I have an application that he cropping to an image and it works correctly in my pc but when uploading it to Jelastic (payara), after finishing the upload it does not show the cropping panel. I have not been able to debug directly from Jelastic because my application is JEE with EJB module and it only allows me to debug with web applications.
please any help.
I am using netbeans 8.2.

Comment: So that we can help you, we need access to your application. Can you provide this access through your service provider by creating an appropriate ticket for it?

Comment: I have created a new environment with payara 4.1.173 and it works correctly.
The error was with the environment with payara 5.182.

Comment: @meyquel, is it Payara related issue or you believe something is wrong with Jelastic?